# Listview is empty

Tags: android, android-listview

I have the following codes as below. I am trying to run a simple list view all with not error and output is empty white screen.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    String[] stateArray = {"jh","kd"};
    private ListView stateListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<string> arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        stateListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.state_list);
        arrayAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        stateListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.lab4_1.MainActivity" >


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/state_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Al works fine no error and the emulator just show empty which screen nothing inside. What could be missing?

Comment: show your array adapter

Comment: For a test I just keep this as my array String[] stateArray = {"jh","kd"};?

Comment: you have to pass the data in adapter to get a the content in list view, please read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html and for example http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not passed your actual data in your adapter that is why its showing listview empty. Simple pass your `stateArray` as last parameter of your adapter as below:

Change your adapter line as below:

```
    String[] stateArray = {"jh","kd"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stateArray);
```

Make your `<string>` as `<String>` you need to make your 'S' capital.

**Note:** The `<String>` part of it all means that the ArrayAdapter will be working with `String[]` data (the paths parameter). In other words, each element in the array will be a `String`.

Comment: I actually tried before and it gives me an error saying that arrayAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stateArray);The constructor ArrayAdapter<R.string>(MainActivity, int, String[]) is undefined

Comment: So what changes must I do here for it to be accepted ?

Comment: Check out my updated answer. @user3953386 Make your `<string>` as `<String>` you need to make your `S` captal.

Comment: So what is the exact problem is it because I set it as private initially?

Comment: Check out updated answer. @user3953386 You have wrongly defined primitive types class for the String value. You have written small 's' besides Capital 'S' of the `String` class.

Comment: Another thing I would like to know where does this comes from android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ?  i am not so clear on this ?

Comment: Its a different forms of layouts which android framework provides you to show the list items in different manners. You can keep it as per your needs. @user3953386

Comment: I am not clear on when your in different manner? You mean its internally built is it?

Comment: Yes its internally built-in layouts. @user3953386

Comment: In future if I got more then 2 select list how to do this .simple_list_item_1 ??

Comment: You can use `.simple_list_item_2`.

Comment: How about for 3 or 4 or more ?

Comment: Go for custom views.Android framework only provides limited and general features which are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
 arrayAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stateArray);
```

Passed your `Array` as third argument of `ArrayAdapter`

For more information go to [AndroidListView/Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is empty because you are not submitting the dataset to the Adapter

```
 arrayAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

Change it in

```
 arrayAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stateArray);
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20T[])) you can find the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
arrayAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

to

```
arrayAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stateArray );
```

Comment: I actually tried before and it gives me an error saying that arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stateArray);The constructor ArrayAdapter<R.string>(MainActivity, int, String[]) is undefined

Comment: Replace `this` with `getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you definition of the generics on the ArrayList are wrong. It needs to say `ArrayList<String>`. Note the capital S.

You need to add Items to you list. The UI Designer is adding sample items automatically, that might have confused you into thinking there would already be items.

Try adding something like `arrayAdapter.add("Test");` at the end of you onCreate().

If that works you can either add your stateArray using:

```
 arrayAdapter.addAll(stateArray)
```

Full MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String[] stateArray = {"jh","kd"};
    private ListView stateListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        stateListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.state_list);
        arrayAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        stateListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        arrayAdapter.add("Test");
        arrayAdapter.addAll(stateArray);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
arrayAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stateArray);
```

Comment: An explanation would improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
adapter.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stringarray));
```

Answer (score 0):

this is empty because you are not passing any data to adapter, the adapter acts as a bridge and is responsible of making the view see this [See Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)

See these examples [Examples](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) this will help you.

Best of luck!